# Python: Why can't you use a self.variable as an optional argument in a method?

Tags: python, class, self

I have created a class where I wanted to pass an self.variable into an optional argument within a method. The reason being because I want to store information in the Self.variable made in an other method, However, If I use the method I would like to have to option to override the self.variable with my own manual information.

Sadly, this is not allowed, therefore I was wondering why not!?
Also, I was wondering if someone knows a Pythonic way to achieve the same objective?

This is an example of what I tried:

```py
# example:

class Example(Object)

    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = []

    def fill_variable(self):
        self.variable = [random.randint(1,10)] * 10

    def use_variable(self, random_numbers = self.variable)
        print(random)

test.Example()
test.fill_variable()
test.use_variable()

# or
test.use_variable(random_numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

My expectation was that `test.use_variable()` would print `10` random numbers
And that `test.use_variable(random_numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])` would
`print(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

Thank you for any kind help and explenation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible, instead you can use an `if` statement checking it it is the same value (`None`) if so, assign it to `self.variable`:

```
def use_variable(self, random_numbers = None):
    if random_numbers == None:
        random_numbers = self.variable
    print(random_numbers)
```

Comment: or you could just do: `self.use_variable = lambda x=self.variable:print(x)` inside your `__init__`, that way you can have it as an optional argument

Answer (score 1):

The code lines at class level which include the `def` lines of the methods are executed at import time once. At this time there is no instance of the class that could be `self` and not even the class is complete yet.

An other point is that the argument name `self` exists **inside** the method only.